# Umbraco ASP.NET Membership Profiles can't create member type properties

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I'm using ASP.NET membership system for membership, roles & profiles.

It's all working but I can't create any properties on my member type/role in Umbraco UI. When I open the member group in Umbraco UI it says 'Not editable from Umbraco'

I've created a profile class that inherits from ProfileBase and I want to use that to provide a link between my Umbraco member properties and the ASP.NET Profile.

Have I done something wrong somewhere?

Here's my custom class:

using System;

using System.Web.Profile;

```
namespace TWBHelper

{

    public class ProfileStandard : ProfileBase

    {

        [SettingsAllowAnonymous(false)]

        public string FirstName

        {

                get

                {

                        var o = base.GetPropertyValue("first_name");

                        if (o == DBNull.Value)

                        {

                                return string.Empty;

                        }

                        return (string)o;

                }

                set

                {

                        base.SetPropertyValue("first_name", value);

                }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your custom class on the web.config as well as the new properties.

This blog post explains how to do it:
http://www.aaron-powell.com/umbraco-members-profiles